# Android Studio files location?

Tags: eclipse, file, android-studio, navigation

So i'm making the switch from eclipse to Android studio, but something that irks me is I can't seem to find where my files are located? In eclipse, right before it boots up, it allows you to pick where they will be, which made it easy for managing and tracking them. Is there a way to do this in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If you start a new project it will show project location, you can choose any location you want to save your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can Copy/Paste your `Eclipse Project` in any folder and reopen it with `Import Project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc.)`.